# Getting remote node IP address in Selenium Grid env

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I need to get the remote node IP which is connected with Selenium grid hub. We are using multiple os platforms (Linux, Mac, Windows).

Any have idea of getting remote node IP in selenium Grid env using java programming?

Answer (score 0):

Below link may be useful to get the remote node ip.

http://selenium.polteq.com/en/get-remote-ip-address-of-node-selenium-grid/

Comment: broken link, could you fix it?